# Finding if neighboring elements exist in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

For the past week I have be struggling to write methods for multidimensional arrays. Here's a picture of something that is related to one exercise that I am doing:

[image]

The author references "ROWS" in his third line of code. The author didn't show his declaration but I assume that he is just comparing `i` to the number of rows in the 2dArray

The author also showed how to test if a top or bottom element exists but not if a horizontal or diagonal value exists.

Using the information provided. Could I please get an example on how to check if an element exists horizontal and diagonal to the specified location. From there I should have enough to piece together the other sides & finish working on a method to compute the average of all neighboring elements in relation to a chosen location within the 2dArray.

Answer (score 0):

The picture actually shows you how to access the left or right and diagonal elements. See the `counts[i - 1][j]` expression in the sample code? See the `[i - 1][j]` in the picture? As you surmised, that shows how to access the top element.

The left element in the picture has the coordinates `[i][j - 1]`. To access it in code, you have to check if the column is at the left of the array and, if not, add it to the `total` value:

```
if (j > 0) { total = total + counts[i][j - 1]; }
```

You should be able to do the same for the rightmost column and the diagonals.